# How to interpret the coefficients in a fractional logit model?

Tags: r, logistic, generalized-linear-model, interpretation, quasi-likelihood

I have some data that is bounded between 0 and 1. I have used the command

```
myfrm <- frm(y, x, linkfrac = 'logit')
```

to fit a regression model with the bounded data as the dependent variable. How do I interpret the coefficients from the regression?

Comment: This is not fractional logit. This is quasi-binomial GLM. It's similar, but not exactly the same thing.

Comment: (Note for the reader: my comment above referred to the `glm` call with `quasibinomial` family. The question has been edited to use `frm`; I don't know what exactly this library is using.)

Comment: The command `frm(...)` is part of the `frm` library